# ArrayList IndexOutOBoundsException after removing an object from ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to find the anagrams of a word in a given input sentence. This is the exception I got when running the program.Is it due to the change in size of the list? Please help me getting out of the problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 66, Size: 66
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:28)
```

Here is my source code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String wordin = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        sc.close();
        List<String> word = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordin.split("\\s+"))); // splits the whole string into array of words
        ArrayList<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i,j;
        for (i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) { // loop to sort letters of a particular word
            word.set(i, word.get(i).replaceAll("[^\\w]", ""));
            char[] ar = word.get(i).toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(ar);
            sorted.add(String.valueOf(ar)); // add the sorted word to list
        }

        for(i=0;i<sorted.size();i++){
            for(j=i;j<sorted.size();j++){
                char[] ar = word.get(j).toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(ar);
                String current = String.valueOf(ar);
                if(current.equals(sorted.get(i))){
                    System.out.println(word.get(j));
                                    word.remove(j);
                }   

            }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The code you've posted never removes anything from the list...

Comment: This is my input :--

Parts of the world have sunlight for close to 24 hours during summer. Dan went to the north pole to lead an expedition during summer. He had a strap on his head to identify himself as the leader.

Comment: what is the 28th line?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code please have a look again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you iterate over sorted collection and removing from word list.

```
for(j=i;j<sorted.size();j++){
   ... 
   word.remove(j); // and now word is shorter than sorted
}
```

you probably need to have `j<word.size()`

Comment: Okay I have iterated the over the word list and it worked. Thanks.